# Jersey JSON support not working

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I followed the official [doc](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html) and tried many already asked SO questions, but nothing is working. Can someone help me finding the issue?

Here I added all the details I could find.

**`web.xml`**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <!-- Register resources and providers under com.stxt.rest package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.stxt.supercentral.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Resource api class**:

```
@Path("/agent")
@Component
public class AgentRestAPI {

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/")
public Response getAgent(@QueryParam("id") String agentId, Profile profile) {
    return ApiResponseFactory.generateResponse(agentId);
}

@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/get")
public Response getAgent(@QueryParam("id") String agentId) {
    return ApiResponseFactory.generateResponse(agentId);
}
```

}

**Resource Class**:

```
public class Profile {

    private String profileId;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String name;

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile{" +
                "profileId='" + profileId + '\'' +
                ", emailAddress='" + emailAddress + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**application.wadl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.2 2013-08-14 08:51:58"/>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/rest/">
        <resource path="/task">
            <resource path="/">
                <method id="getTask" name="GET">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
                    </request>
                    <response/>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
        <resource path="/customer">
            <resource path="/">
                <method id="getCustomer" name="GET">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
                    </request>
                    <response/>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
        <resource path="/agent">
            <resource path="/get">
                <method id="getAgent" name="GET">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
            <resource path="/">
                <method id="getAgent" name="POST">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
        <resource path="application.wadl">
            <method id="getWadl" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml"/>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                </request>
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                </request>
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <resource path="{path}">
                <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="path" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
                <method id="geExternalGrammar" name="GET">
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="apply" name="OPTIONS">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

**Request Details POST**:

General:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/rest/agent?id=23
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length:352
Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Server:Jetty(9.3.0.v20150612)
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:17
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=1e6smzkea0dds17t964t3u7fc2
CSP:active
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
```

Query String Parameters:

```
id:23
```

Request Payload:

```
{"profileId": "1"}
```

Response:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Error 415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
    </head>
    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 415</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /rest/agent. Reason:
            <pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.0.v20150612</a><hr/>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Request Details GET**:

General:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/rest/agent/get?id=23
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-transform, max-age=0
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:application/json
Server:Jetty(9.3.0.v20150612)
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=132gft2iqjdzgcrn6eliv77ox
Host:localhost:8080
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
```

Query String Parameters:

```
id:23
```

Response:

```
"23"
```

**Attached libraries**:
There can be extra unused libraries (which I may have added while trying some solutions on the web).

```
asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b14.jar
cglib-2.2.0-b14.jar
hk2-api-2.2.0-b14.jar
hk2-locator-2.2.0-b14.jar
hk2-utils-2.2.0-b14.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-server.jar
activation-1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
jersey-core-1.19.jar
jersey-json-1.19.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
```

Comment: How and where is the call to the backend being made?

Comment: I am using Postman Rest client extension to make the `POST` call. Don't know what you are trying to ask in `where` part, but the server is running on same machine and `GET` request is working fine.

Comment: When you make the request with Postman do you set the mime type to "application/javascript"? Can you also post the working GET endpoint?

Comment: I updated the question to include GET details, pls see above.

I didn't set the mime type details. Don't know how to do it. But I did set the content-type to `application/json`

Comment: Can you remove the @Path("/")  annotation from the post getProfile method?  That seems wrong to me.

Comment: It should not create problem. I have used it in past. But as you suggested I tried removing it also, but still the same response.

Comment: In which package does your Profile pojo resides? Is it accessible to Jersey servlet?

Comment: @GauravVarma Its in `com.stxt.superbase.bean`. In web.xml I defined jersey package as  `com.stxt.supercentral.rest`. This shouldn't be an issue. But as you said I tried it after moving `Profile` to `com.stxt.supercentral.rest`, still the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved. In Jersey `2.*` we need to register `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriters` manually. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925392/getting-jersey-2-x-pojo-json-support-to-work-with-jetty) questions explains it well.